# New TailwindCSS utility classes not hot reloading /pages directory in NuxtJS 3 (Vue)

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I was experiencing a problem with new tailwindcss utility modules not hot reloading but only for my /pages file and not my /components or /layout files. Classes used when I initial ran `npm run dev` would load correctly but if I changed a class to something not previously used it wouldn't load (ie: `bg-red-400` to `bg-red-500`). The tailwindcss import were included in a main.css file that was imported in the nuxt.config.ts ie:

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from "nuxt/config"; 
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: ["@/assets/css/main.css"],
})
```

I already have a solution and it's posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why this worked but removing the style tags from _app.vue fixed it. Even if the style tag included the tailwindcss imports, the hot reload wouldn't work. I included the css in my nuxt.config.ts

nuxt.config.ts:

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from "nuxt/config";

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  build: {
    postcss: {
      postcssOptions: {
        plugins: {
          "postcss-import": {},
          "tailwindcss/nesting": {},
          tailwindcss: {},
          autoprefixer: {},
        },
      },
    },
  },
  css: ["@/assets/css/main.css"],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      fs: require.resolve("rollup-plugin-node-builtins"),
    },
  },
});
```

The main.css included the tailwindcss imports

main.css:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

As a side note, if any of your /pages files include a style tag that would also cause them to not hot reload.

I original saw the solution on reddit but couldn't find a stack overflow solution so I hope this can help someone. https://www.reddit.com/r/tailwindcss/comments/p7h7yn/with_tailwindcss_nuxt_js_doesnt_autoreload_with/